# Google Adwords API OfflineConversionFeedService return INVALID_STRING_DATE_TIME

Tags: c#, api, datetime, google-ads-api

I am trying to  make a conversion in AdWords Api with a Adwords test account:

```
            OfflineConversionFeed feed = new OfflineConversionFeed();
            feed.conversionName = conversionName;
            feed.conversionTime = conversionTime;
            feed.conversionValue = conversionValue;
            feed.googleClickId = gClid;
```

I am using the latest [AdWords .NET libriary](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-adwords-dotnet-lib) by @AnashOommen

I keep getting from my API request the following exception:

---

An exception occurred while running this code example. System.ApplicationExcepti
on: Failed upload offline conversions. ---> Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.Lib.AdWordsAp
iException: An API exception has occurred. See ApiException and InnerException f
ields for more details. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: **DateEr
ror.INVALID_STRING_DATE_TIME @ ; trigger:'7/14/2014 6:30:00 AM'**
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClie
ntMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)

---

One more thing, I found that in Adwords documentation:

> All time zones must be in full hour or half-hour increments relative to Greenwich Mean Time. If your local time zone is one of the few offset a quarter-hour from GMT, the AdWords system can't support your time zone. Please choose a different time zone for your account.

I tried many date formats such:

1. YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS
2. MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

And many more, non of them worked.

My local time is different then the time zone in my test account( Central Standard Time ) I prefer not to change the time in my test account because i want it to be the same as the production account.

Any help would by appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

With a little help from Adsword support, the right format is : **20140714 060000 Europe/Berlin**

I added the timezone (Europe/Berlin) next to the date.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HHmmss") + " Europe/Berlin";
```

That solved the INVALID_STRING_DATE_TIME error.

Comment: Did you see the table of date formats in the FAQ?  (https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2998031)  And I wouldn't worry if the time zone you specify is off by a bit.  Remember, AdWords reports conversions based on the time of the previous click.  Not based on the conversion time you report.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP usually requires values in ISO8601 format, and should include a time zone offset.

For example: `2014-07-14T01:23:45-05:00`

Assuming `conversionTime` is a `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` type, try formatting it with the [ISO8601 compliant "round-trip format specifier"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip):  `.ToString("o")`.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Johnson, I have tried all the described formats including a hard coded date - "2014-07-14T01:23:45-05:00", still same error result, I added the full error description above